# How do I tell mdadm to start using a missing disk in my RAID5 array again?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-raid, raid-5, mdadm

I have a 3-disk RAID array running in my Ubuntu server. This has been running flawlessly for over a year but I was recently forced to strip, move and rebuild the machine.

When I had it all back together and ran up Ubuntu, I had some problems with disks not being detected. A couple of reboots later and I'd solved that issue. The problem now is that the 3-disk array is showing up as degraded every time I boot up. For some reason it seems that Ubuntu has made a new array and added the missing disk to it.

I've tried stopping the new 1-disk array and adding the missing disk, but I'm struggling. On startup I get this:

```
root@uberserver:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md_d1 : inactive sdf1[2](S)
      1953511936 blocks

md0 : active raid5 sdg1[2] sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdh1[0]
      2930279808 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

I have two RAID arrays and the one that normally pops up as md1 isn't appearing.

I read somewhere that calling `mdadm --assemble --scan` would re-assemble the missing array so I've tried first stopping the existing array that ubuntu started:

```
root@uberserver:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md_d1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md_d1
```

...and then tried to tell ubuntu to pick the disks up again:

```
root@uberserver:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/1 has been started with 2 drives (out of 3).
```

So that's started md1 again but it's not picking up the disk from md_d1:

```
root@uberserver:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sde1[1] sdf1[2]
      3907023872 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]

md_d1 : inactive sdd1[0](S)
      1953511936 blocks

md0 : active raid5 sdg1[2] sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdh1[0]
      2930279808 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

**What's going wrong here? Why is Ubuntu trying to pick up `sdd1` into a different array?
How do I get that missing disk back home again?**

**[Edit]** - I realised I hadn't added md1 to auto start in `mdadm.conf`. After adding the md1 to `mdadm.conf` it now tries to mount the array on startup but it's still missing `sdd1`. If I tell it to try and assemble automatically I get the impression it knows it needs `sdd1` but can't use it:

```
root@uberserver:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
/dev/md1: File exists
mdadm: /dev/md/1 already active, cannot restart it!
mdadm:   /dev/md/1 needed for /dev/sdd1...
```

**What am I missing?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this was the cleanest way to resolve the issue, but the following appears to have got it going again:

```
root@uberserver:~# mdadm --stop /dev/md_d1
mdadm: stopped /dev/md_d1

root@uberserver:~# mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: re-added /dev/sdd1

root@uberserver:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sdd1[3] sde1[1] sdf1[2]
      3907023872 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]
      [>....................]  recovery =  0.0% (121728/1953511936) finish=1337.0min speed=24345K/sec

md0 : active raid5 sdg1[2] sdc1[3] sdb1[1] sdh1[0]
      2930279808 blocks level 5, 64k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
```

Still don't understand why it couldn't just add the disk back in :-/

Comment: A tool that could come in handy is "mdadm --examine".  Another thing to consider is the DEVICE lines in /etc/mdadm.conf.  Did they neglect to mention /dev/sdd1?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem - possibly a loose power cable caused my array to drop a drive - so mdstat showed [U_UU] and the drive also vanished for other tools such as SeaChest. After reseating all the connectors the drive reappeared but mdadm didn't automatically recover. It seemed to have simply dropped it.

`me@server:~$ sudo mdadm --details /dev/md0`

showed the drive as removed even though it was present and functioning and had the correct UUID tags.

To recover I just had to run:

`me@server:~$ sudo mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1`

and it immediately added the drive and started recovery (didn't need to stop the array first).