# How do I stop ubuntu waiting for me to "Press S to skip or C to continue..." when it fails to mount on startup?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, boot, automount

I've been having [some issues](https://superuser.com/questions/443321/how-do-i-tell-mdadm-to-start-using-a-missing-disk-in-my-raid5-array-again) with my RAID setup recently on my headless Ubuntu 10.04 server which means one of my mount requests is failing on bootup. Clearly, I need to fix the RAID issue, but this machine is in my loft, and having to crawl up there with a keyboard just so I can hit S a few times is extremely irritating.

The exact message is as follows:

> The disk drive for /drv/photos is not ready yet or not present
>
> Continue to wait; or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

I'd still like Ubuntu to try and mount it, but is there any way to tell it not to wait for the device?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120/how-do-i-avoid-the-s-to-skip-message-on-boot You might have to add `nobootwait`

Answer (score 3):

Find out in which partition you facing error.. like it shows /partition name.. remember that partition and  in your terminal type this,

```
gksu gedit /etc/fstab
```

Locate the line showing your partition where getting mount error... and add to the options section the following:

```
nobootwait
```

like this,

```
UUID=XXXXX    /    partition    nobootwait,etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly sub-optimal as a solution but you could always try moving that mount command to the `/etc/rc.local` file so it's not a locking operation.

Comment: In what way is that sub-optimal?

Comment: @JonCage - it's sub-optimal because mounts are normally handled through fstab - putting boot-time mount commands in random places makes it harder to understand what your system is doing at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me:

If you not able to boot into ubuntu, then use the below commands after typing (ctrl+alt+f1);

```
sudo mv /tmp /tmp_old 
sudo mkdir /tmp 
sudo chmod -R 777 /tmp
sudo rm -Rf /tmp_old
```

Otherwise, add the following line to /etc/fstab :

```
tmpfs  /tmp   tmpfs     defaults       0      0
```

Restart, and that would not appear. However, I commented this line from the fstab again, after problem was resolved, and this would still be fine, over subsequent boot ups.

For more [info](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-this-issue-occuring-in-Ubuntu-boot/answer/Atif-Imam?srid=zOEC), visit the link.